# Calculated column based on data in linked list in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: lookup-column

I have two sharepoint lists:

- one with all budget positions
- one with all cost centers

the budget positions have a lookup column that links to an entry in the cost center list.
What I would like to do now, is to have an additional column in the cost center list that shows me the sum of all budget positions linked to this cost center.

Is that possible with SP2010? If not, is there a workaround / other possibility to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box support in SharePoint. And doing aggregations is not the strongest part of SharePoint.

The only real option is to add event receivers to the list with budget postings updating a "readonly" column i Cost Center on every ListItem add, update and delete.

Comment: Really sad ... :-(